# searching csv file, which is best practice?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, search

I have a CSV file which looks like this:
(in my CSV there are no headers, but I add them here for clarity)

```
geneName, personNumber, allele1, allele2
gene-1-A, PERSON1, C, G
gene-2_s, PERSON1, A, C
gene_3_D, PERSON1, T, T
.
.
.
gene-1_A, PERSON2, G, G
gene_3_D, PERSON2, A, C
.
.
etc.
```

Each person can have a 50k genes, and in file I have for example 400 people.

I need to implement some conditions like:

```
if personX has allele1 in gene-1_A = "A" AND allele1 in gene-1_A = "B" then add to results.txt "PersonX 'cancer possible'"
```

Important in this case:
sometimes 2 genes need to be checked. 
For example:

```
if (gene1 = 'A' AND 'B') AND (gene213213 = 'G' AND 'G') THEN add then add to results.txt "PersonX 'cancer possible'"
```

But the conditions are not a problem. I can write it. But what about searching genes in files. I can't index it because sometimes one person has a gene and another does not.

I know how to do it in two ways:

1. Read the whole CSV file by pandas to memory, and then create new column creating conditions by replace function or use some different way. but it's still load whole file to memory.
2. Read file line by line by pure python and check each line. In first case if one gene is good, save result in new column. In second case when I need to check 2 or more genes I can save results in variables. Less memory used (I think) but much longer.

That's my two proposition, and I don't know which is better to use in this case. It's highly probably that my solutions aren't the best solution for that problem, so If you have another idea, I will be glad for help.

In result I need to save all possible ill persons in a new file. But it's not a problem to move them.

Comment: Do you get memory errors if you implement it in your version 1? What's the problem there?

Comment: I have many files, and if they are < 10GB it's ok, but >10gb it's could be a problem. I want to create optimal, universal module to my data preparing tool.

Comment: Writing the interesting records to a separate file is much easier and more efficient than moving them (i.e. removing them from the input file and then writing them). With this, approach #2 seems easy, natural, and efficient. Write the problematic record to the new file and forget it.

Comment: From the description it would seem you only need to keep one person's data in memory at each time. No need to load all the data at once for all files

Comment: @GPhilo tha't correct. Ok, so I will try to solve it in that way. I'ts looks more like 2nd solution with specific read atribiutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 pd.read_csv(r'../input/data.csv', chunksize='choose your size')
```

you can read the file in chunks and you still have the powerful pandas techniques such as grouping